# Is it possible to add header to message in router?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have router which returns names of the channels (as expected):

```
public String route(Message<CustomEntity> msg) {
    ...        
    return "toAdd";
    ...
    return "toUpd";
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to add new header to message in router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. This is not a router responsibility to mutate message. You need to use a `HeaderEnricher` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-enricher

The header can be populated by the SpEL or `Function` at runtime against request message.